# Intent filter does not open the activity on S7 Edge

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, intentfilter

I am working on Oauth2 authentication where my callback is X://callback. After the user authorizes my app to his resources, the tokens are redirected to X://callback

I had the following activity in my app with an intent filter declared.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".myapp.OCompleteAuth"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="X" android:host="callback" android:pathPattern="/.*"/>


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The below is the build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nanthealth.authorizedcx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

when the user hits the allow button to authorize my app , the activity "OCompleteAuth" needs to be started.

It works fine on Samsung Galaxy s6 , but not on Samsung Galaxy s7 edge.

Has anyone faced similar issues on S7 edge. Is there any setting that needs to be enabled.

Thanks in advance for your help.